# adjust contrast on non-selected portion of image

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I have an image taken of a room directly at a sunny window. When I adjust the image brightness and contrast the window turns white.

Is it possible use the wand to select the the portion of the image I *don't* want to be affected by the brightness/contrast treatment?

I am I approaching this wrong way altogether?

Thanks

Comment: inverse selection?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! It would be most helpful if you could add some screenshots. This saves everybody time, and makes it more likely that you will get helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the adjustment layers, found at the lowest portion of your layers panel.  It's the black and white circular icon.  When you click this icon, you will find all the standard adjustment options: curves, hue/saturation, and levels.  Create this layer above your image and make adjustments until the areas you want adjusted are satisfactory.  Then edit the masking portion of this layer to mask out areas that you want to remain as original.  You can continue this process with as many masked adjustment layers as you like.

This may not be the ideal example image, but you can see the steps to follow here:
The orginal is on top, adjustment applied below, and mask enabled last.

[image]

I didn't spend too much time trying to refine this, but I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the wand how you see fit to select the area you *don't* want to adjust contrast to; then duplicate the selection to a new layer in the same position.

Then adjust the contrast on the original layer how you want, thus leaving the top layer unaffected.

The problem you may get though is that the adjusted layer may look too different to the original and it will look like it's sitting on top of the image.